# saving an output to .xml format

Tags: php, mysql, xml, google-maps, output

I a working on a sample project that gives positions of Telecom operators cell towers based on regions on google maps.

I am following the steps from the google maps API how-to
[google maps instructions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/mysql-to-maps#echoxml)

i am stuck here. I have followed all the instructions and i am also getting XML output on my webpage from the database. Now as per the instructions that i have to follow, i have to save this output to an .XML file to my server for further processing, and adding markers on the google maps. The markers include the Lat - Long values and some information on the cell towers selected: cell-id, Location code and radio type.

I have searched for the solution but i am stuck at - PHP: DOMDocument::save and how to implement in my code.

The code for the same is attached for reference:

```
function parseToXML($htmlStr) {
    $xmlStr = str_replace('<','&lt;',$htmlStr);
    $xmlStr = str_replace('>','&gt;',$htmlStr);
    $xmlStr = str_replace('"','&quot;',$htmlStr);
    $xmlStr=str_replace("'",'&#39;',$xmlStr);
    $xmlStr = str_replace('&','&amp;',$htmlStr);
    return $xmlStr;
}


$t_query = "SELECT `radio_type`, `lac`,`cell-id`,`longitude`,`latitude` FROM `".DBNAME."`.`celltower` WHERE `mcc` = '".$mcc."' AND `mnc` = '".$mnc."'";

$t_query_exec = mysqli_query($con, $t_query);

if($t_num_rows = 0) {
    die("Unable to fetch any data..Please try again..!!");
} else {
    header("Content-type: text/xml");

    //Begin XML file, echo parent node.

    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
    echo '<root>';
    echo '<markers>';
    //Iterating through rows, and printing XML nodes for each
    while($t_var = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t_query_exec)) {
        //Add to XML document node.
        echo '<marker ';
        echo 'radio_type="' .parseToXML($t_var['radio_type']) . '" ';
        echo 'lac="' .parseToXML($t_var['lac']) . '" ';
        echo 'cell-id="' .parseToXML($t_var['cell-id']) . '" ';
        echo 'longitude="' . $t_var['longitude'] . '" ';
        echo 'latitude="' .$t_var['latitude'] . '" ';
        echo '/>';
    }

    echo '</markers>';
    echo '</root>'; 
}
```

i just need to know that how can i save the output to an .XML file
Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php

Comment: Thanks a lot.. will refer it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put your XML into a variable and save it with `file_put_contents()`

```
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>';
$xmlString .=  '<root>';
$xmlString .=  '<markers>';
//Iterating through rows, and printing XML nodes for each
while($t_var = mysqli_fetch_assoc($t_query_exec)) {
    //Add to XML document node.
    $xmlString .=  '<marker ';
    $xmlString .=  'radio_type="' .parseToXML($t_var['radio_type']) . '" ';
    $xmlString .=  'lac="' .parseToXML($t_var['lac']) . '" ';
    $xmlString .=  'cell-id="' .parseToXML($t_var['cell-id']) . '" ';
    $xmlString .=  'longitude="' . $t_var['longitude'] . '" ';
    $xmlString .=  'latitude="' .$t_var['latitude'] . '" ';
    $xmlString .=  '/>';
}

$xmlString .=  '</markers>';
$xmlString .=  '</root>';   

file_put_contents('output.xml', $xmlString);
```